# Junit Testing with SpringFramework, without Maven : Error - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I'm new with JUnit - Spring Framework.

What I'm doing is, creating some Tests for my Application. Here is Code what I have did.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class InspirdTests {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformBLL platform;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    @Before
    public void settingUp(){
        System.out.println("Before SetUp");
    }

    @Test
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Before : " + platform);
        platform.getAllProjectsForPlatform(null);
        System.out.println("After : " + platform);
    }
}
```

and the Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I'm just blocked, Im stucked with it, i just cant move ahead.

What I have tried:

1. A lot google, but the result is as it is.
2. I had made some blank Methods for Testing, Still Result is as it is.
3. I have added `JUnit-4.12.jar` into **WEB-INF/lib/**
4. I have added `Junit 4` into **Java Build Path**

Guys please Help me to Find out Solution for it.

Comment: There is no need to add junit.jar to `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Which spring-test version do you use?

Comment: @Jens I have tried that too, but its not Working. I'm using **Spring-Test-2.5.6**

Comment: Then you should use `Junit 4.5.`. But spring 2.5 is very old. You should think about upgrade.

Comment: @Jens Ok, Let me try.

Comment: @Jens : Should I add it into **WEB-INF/lib** or into **Build Path**??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78972/discussion-between-hps-411-and-jens).

Answer (score 0):

Include `spring-test` and `junit` jars in your eclipse buildpath.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;


@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/conf/applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MongoRepositoryImplTest {

    @Autowired
      MongoRepositoryImpl mongoRepositoryImpl;

    @Test
    public void testGetMongoConnectionFromFactory() {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Config file should look like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.client.impl" />

    <bean id="mongoRepositoryImpl" class="com.client.impl.MongoRepositoryImpl">
        <constructor-arg name="connectionName" value="testCases"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```